# Proof of $\frac{d \sqrt{x}}{dx}$ including proof of the limit?

Tags: derivatives

Looking at proofs for $\frac{d \sqrt{x}}{dx}$, ($0<x$) they often get to this point:

$$ \frac{d \sqrt{x}}{dx} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x + h}} $$

At this point magical limits are taken. Unfortunately I'm trying to prove this in Coq so need to use a formal definition of the limit e.g. the limit of $f(x)$ at $c$ is $l$ means:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0,\ \exists \delta \ s.t.\ |x-c|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x) -l| < \epsilon$$

I think that this gives me the following:

$$|h| < \delta \Rightarrow \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x + h}} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \right| < \epsilon $$

It's at this point that I get stuck trying to find a $\delta$ to satisfy this equation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The equation you wrote is not the point to which we usually get: the limit sign is missing on the right hand side; the quantity inside the left hand limit does not look correct;...

Comment: Can not use previous results if f(x) is continuous and doesn't involve dividing by zero lim f(h) = f(lim h)?  That's what the magic refered to is.  Any way we want .... hmmm.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for the comment, I'm very rusty at this (having done my degree more than 10 years ago now and not used this stuff since), and had forgotten about that result. Looking at my real analysis book proving that the function is continuous at $c$ means $\forall \epsilon >0\ \exists \delta >0\ s.t.\ |x-c|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$ :-(

Comment: @fleablood Looks like I could go about proving it's continuous by demonstrating that $x^2$ is continuous and injective on the interval $(0, \inf)$ implying that $sqrt{x}$ is continuous and monotonic, and then use the result that you suggested. All the solutions I've found involve using inverse function rules. Seams a pity to not be able to find a $\delta$!

Comment: The "magic" is that $h \rightarrow 0$ so just replace the $h$ with $0$ and you get the result no problems.  It's pretty "obvious" that if you can replace the $h$ with $0$ and get a "nice" answer we are fine.  It's when we get dividing by 0s or multiplying by infinities things get hard... fine but why?  how can we know if h goes to zero (x^2 + 2hx + h^2)/(\sqrt{x + h} goes to $x^2/\sqrt{x}$? Finding the proper epsilon delta is kinda hard.  better to do a general case.  h->a then x+h -> x+a, $\sqrt{h}->a, and 1/x -> 1/a.  Put them together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right|&=\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+h}}{2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}\right|\\\\
&=\left|\frac{h}{2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})^2}\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{|h|}{2x^{3/2}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Working through this a little way, setting $\delta = 8x^{3/2}\cdot \epsilon$ gives $\frac{|h|}{8x^{3/2}} < \epsilon$ unfortunately I can't then use your previous result because it doesn't hold when $h$ is negative because of the absolute value symbols. Have I missed something?

Comment: @Dr.MV, it should be $|h|\lt\delta=\epsilon\cdot8x^{3/2}$, not $\epsilon/8x^{3/2}$, in your comment above.  And to be hyperprecise (which I think Coq demands), it should be $\delta=\min\{\epsilon\cdot8x^{3/2},x\}$ to make sure $\sqrt{x+h}$ stays non-negative.

Comment: @barrycipra Yes, of course.  This shows the perils of using a "not-so-smart" phone when one's eyes are older.  And of course we need to bound $x+h$ away from the negatives.  This post was a hint only.  And your comments help finish that which was to be shown.  Much appreciative! -Mark

Comment: My issue with this answer is that $\left| \frac{h}{2 \sqrt{x} (\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x})^2} \right| \leq \frac{|h|}{8x^{3/2}}$ isn't true. If $h$ is negative then the result doesn't hold. Looks like the correct inequality at the end is $< \frac{|h|}{2x^{3/2}}$ which always holds.

Comment: @JamesSnook This is not an answer, but rather a HINT (note the bold-face word that begins the post).  And $h<0$ is permitted provided $x+h\ge 0$ (if we are restricting analysis to the reals).   I've edited with the case $h<0$ included.

Comment: @Dr.MV I understand that it was a hint, and really appreciate it, as it was enough to help me. My only issue is that it was factually incorrect, and someone else looking at it may not have noticed that it was wrong whenever $h$ was negative, so I didn't want to accept it as the answer.

Comment: James, much appreciative for your taking time to go through this and work out the details yourself.  And you're correct; I should have added $h>0$ to the initial post.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we could prove the following lemma:

If $\lim_{h\rightarrow a} f(h) = m$ then

i) $\lim_{h\rightarrow a} (f(h) + w) = m + w = (\lim_{h\rightarrow a} f(h)) + w$.

ii) if $m \ge 0$ then $\lim_{h\rightarrow a}\sqrt{h} = \sqrt{m} = \sqrt{\lim_{h\rightarrow a}f(h)}$

iii) if $m \ne 0$ then $\lim_{h\rightarrow a}\frac{1}{f(h)} = 1/m = \frac 1{\lim_{h\rightarrow a}f(h)}$

Then we'd pretty much be done.

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(x + h) = x + \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h = x + 0=x$

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\sqrt{x + h} = \sqrt{\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(x+h)} = \sqrt{x}$

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+h}) = \sqrt{x} + \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\sqrt{x + h} = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x} = 2\sqrt{x}$.

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac 1{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+h}} = \frac 1{\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+h})} = 1/2\sqrt{x}$.

Done.

Must prove lemmma.

i) For $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ so that $|h - a| < \delta \implies |f(h) - m| < \epsilon$ so $|h-a| < \delta \implies |(f(h)+w)-(m+w)|= |f(h) -m| < \epsilon$.

ii) For $2\sqrt{m} > \epsilon > 0$ let $\gamma = 2\sqrt{m}\epsilon - \epsilon^2 > 0$.

There is a $\delta$ so that $|h - a| < \delta \implies |f(h) - m| < \gamma$

$\implies m - \gamma < f(h) < m + \gamma $

$\implies (\sqrt{m} - \epsilon)^2 = m - 2\sqrt{m}\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < f(h) < m + 2\sqrt{m}\epsilon - \epsilon^2 < m + 2\sqrt{m}\epsilon + \epsilon^2=(\sqrt{m} + \epsilon)^2$

$\implies \sqrt{m} - \epsilon < f(h) < \sqrt{m} + \epsilon$

$\implies |f(h) - \sqrt{m}| < \epsilon$.

iii)  For $ \epsilon > 0$.  Let $\epsilon_2 =   \min(|m|/2, m^2*\epsilon/2) > 0$.  (Remember $m \ne 0$, so we can be assured $\epsilon_2 > 0$.)

We can find a $\delta$ so that $|h-a| < \delta \implies |f(h) - m| < \epsilon_2$.

So $|h-a| < \delta \implies |f(h) - m| < \epsilon_2 \le |m|/2 \implies |f(h)| > |m|/2$.

So if $|h - a| < \delta$ then

$|\frac 1{f(h)} - \frac 1m| = |\frac{m - f(h)}{m*f(h)}| = |m - f(h)|*\frac 1{|m*f(h)|}$

$< |m-f(h)|*\frac 1{m^2/2} < \epsilon_2*\frac 2{m^2}$

$\le  \frac{m^2\epsilon}{2}*\frac 2{m^2}=\epsilon$.

So we proved the lemma and thus the result.

===

Actually let's see what Mr. Rudin says.  In Principles of Mathematical Analysis by walter rudin we have in chapter 4.

Theorem 4.4.  Suppose $E \subset X$ a metric space (*we'll just say $X$ and $E$ are $\mathbb R$*), $p$ is a limit point of $E$ (*that just means we talk about $x \rightarrow p$*), $f$ and $g$ are complex functions on $E$ (*let's just say $f$ and $g$ are real functions*) and

$\lim_{x \rightarrow p}f(x) = A$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}g(x) = B$ then

a) $\lim_{x \rightarrow p}(f + g)(x)=A+B$

b) $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}(fg)(x) = AB$

c) $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}(f/g)(x) = A/B$ if $B\ne 0$.

The proof of a) and c) are as I gave them.  b) is pretty basic and similar.

Then Def 4.5 defines continuous functions.  ($f$ is continuous at $p$, if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that for all $x$ where $d(x,p)< \delta$ it follows that $d(f(x),f(p)) < \epsilon$)

Theorem 4.6: $f$ is continuous at $p$ if and only if $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x) = f(p)$.  This follows purely by definitions.

Thereom 4.7: says that composition of continuous functions are continuous.  The proof is simple.  Basically you find $\epsilon, \gamma, \delta$ so that $|x-p|< \gamma \implies |f(x) - f(p)| < \epsilon$ and $|x-p|<\delta \implies |h(x) - h(p)|<\gamma$ there for $|x-p| < \delta \implies |h(x) - h(p)| < \gamma \implies |f(h(x)) - f(h(p))| < \epsilon$ so $f(h(x))$ is continuous at $p$..

With those we just have to show $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous which is basically my lemma ii).

Answer (score 0):

Not having used Coq and only having the slightest idea about theorem provers....

*Humans* don't resort to epsilon delta proofs unless they need to. They spend lots of time learning the various interesting algebraic properties that limits, etc have.

Although it's not phrased this way at first, one of the first key ideas a student learns is, for spaces $X$ and $Y$, there is a subtype $\mathcal{C}(X, Y) \subseteq Y^X$ of *continuous* functions. Then we have

- The restriction of the limit to $\mathcal{C}(X, Y) \times X \to Y$ is a total function that is identical to the restriction of the evaluation map $Y^X \times X \to Y$
- Composition of functions restricts to a map $\mathcal{C}(Y,Z) \times \mathcal{C}(X,Y) \to \mathcal{C}(X, Z)$

Together with basic facts you should have proven prior:

- Addition is an element of $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$
- Division is an element of $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})), \mathbb{R})$
- The square root is an element of $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}, \mathbb{R})$
- Constant functions are elements of $\mathcal{C}(\{ * \}, \mathbb{R})$

you can prove that, for every $x > 0$,

$$ h \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}} $$

is an element of $\mathcal{C}((-x, \infty), \mathbb{R})$.